# How to correctly use lists inside Compile

Tags: compile

Consider the following code:

```
Compile[{{x,_Real}},Module[{x1=x,W},
 W=RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 10^-2], 2];
 x1=x1+W[[1]]+W[[2]];
 x1]]
```

It fails complaining that `W[[1]],W[[2]]` is longer that the depth of the variable. How to correctly use a list inside `Compile`?

Comment: There is probably no point in "compiling" `RandomVariate`. The backend of `RandomVariate` should be compiled already.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I know, I am sorry. This is just a MWE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
cp = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, 
Module[{x1 = x, W = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 10^-2], 2]}, 
x1 = x1 + W[[1]] + W[[2]];x1]]
```

Comment: It works, thanks. But why is my code wrong? It seems the same as yours...

Comment: Probably because `Compile` has to know the size of `W`

Comment: Your code works if you change `Module` to `Block` !