# Why does changing this code in a Compile make it work?

Tags: compile, scoping

This is a follow up question to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/258974/8822) one. In that question I asked why the following code didn't work:

```
Compile[{{x, _Real}}, 
  Module[{x1 = x, W},
    W = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 10^-2], 2];
    x1 = x1 + W[[1]] + W[[2]];
    x1
  ]
]
```

Ulrich Neumann mentioned that I should modify it by inserting the definition of `W` inside the curly brackets in `Module`. He also found that the code works if I change `Module` with `Block`.

Why is it so?

Comment: `Module` and `Block` are interchangeable within `Compile`. `Block` basically gets treated like `Module` inside `Compile` because the distinction in the kernel does not have meaning inside the WVM.  I'm not sure that this is documented, but you see `Block` in `Compile` a lot on this site. (It can have an effect different from `Module` if the code can't be run in the WVM and it falls back on symbolic evaluation.)